# Parser builders for C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I want to write a simple DSL in C#. Nothing too complicated. I'm looking for the .NET equivalent of Lex & Yacc. The easiest one I've found so far is GOLD Parser builder. The other choice is to use the lex & yacc available with F#, but I'm not keen to program in F# right now.

If you have any suggestions for the .NET version of Lex or Yacc, I'd love to hear them!

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to stay in C#, I would recommend using the [Irony toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/irony) - it allows you to specify grammars in C# code.

Answer (score 3):

[ANTLR 3](http://www.antlr.org/) has a C# [target](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target).

Answer (score 1):

How much F# programming do you need to do to take advantage of the Lex & Yacc?  Can you throw what you need into an F# dll, and reference it from a C# project?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but [Oslo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/oslo/default.aspx) has the ability to create a textual DSL.

It's got more features than that, but you can ignore all the repository and Grand Vision stuff and just produce a grammar you can use to parse your DSL into an AST. Alternatively, you can take advantage of the built-in support for parsing into a set of rows in a database.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a C# Lex and C# CUP that I found on a Vienna University website

[C# Lex Manual](http://www.seclab.tuwien.ac.at/projects/cuplex//lex.htm)

Comment: Has anyone used this? I am using it and I seem to be running into some issues during the parse. Did anyone find it stable? Any positive feedback to report? Any drawbacks to be aware of?

Comment: Lexer has small issues (easy fixable), parser have bigger issues. The project (C# JLex+CUP) is longer maintained. I tried to recreate entire parser part (by translating original from Java to C#), but it appeared too complex and not worth the time.